# how to convert an e.item.dataitem to type (Of T)

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework, generics, itemdatabound

I'm trying to do this in an item_databound event of a datagrid in asp.net

```
Dim EntType As EmployeeEntity = DirectCast(e.Item.DataItem, EmployeeEntity )
```

but I encounter the error

> Cannot convert to class EmployeeEntity

The EmployeeEntity class has the same members as the items in e.Item.DataItem's DataRowView items. 
so how else do i cast the contents, without having to actually set each property of EemployeeEnity individually, from  the e.Item.DataItem ?

Comment: A dataItem would be the underlying dataview of the datasource the datagrid items are being bound to. most commonly you would find this code. dim dr as datarow = Ctype( e.item.dataItem, DataRowview).row

Comment: I realize that.  What are you binding to?

Comment: **What are you binding it to**?

Comment: trying to bind it to a List(of EmployeeEntity).

Comment: Then `DataItem` should be an `EmployeeEntity`.  What do you see in the debugger?

Comment: you are correct. actually the datasource is a datatable of the Employee table. (sorry about the confusion earlier). in trying to make it easier to read, i'd li

Comment: you are correct. actually the datasource is a datatable (sorry about confusing before). in trying to make it easier to read, i'd like to cast it to Type entity to be able to access/assign the properties easily eg. if EmployeeEntity.Active then EmployeeEntity.Update()... end if. the reason i'd like to use datatable for a datasource is because objectDatasource control allows sorting with dataTables & Datasets but not with a list (of object)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot magically turn one type into another, even if they have the same properties.

You need to copy the properties yourself.

Answer (score 0):

One word, [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)